# Magento 2 Get product Bundle items

Tags: product, configurable-product, custom-options, bundled-product

I am working on a module where I need to get a product's bundle items information as it is displaying in the Product display page.

For product display Page the option are available through options.phtml

```
<?php /** @var $block Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle */ ?>
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$stripSelection = $product->getConfigureMode() ? true : false;
$options = $block->decorateArray($block->getOptions($stripSelection));
?>
```

how can I get the same in my php file?